# Individually Styling Data Labels for Bar Chart

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to style individual data labels for a bar chart?

I would like to position each data label at the 0 axis point(for the chart) underneath each bar. However, if i signify x:0 for the data labels, it is different for each bar length. Can i get it to the 0 axis for the chart(with 5px padding:)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add example in jsFiddle? Are you referencing to bar or column chart?

Comment: thanks: http://jsfiddle.net/tredington/zLE5R/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case you can translate that labels using simple hack, see:

```
        events: {
            load: function(){
                for(var i = 0; i < this.series[0].data.length; i++) {
                    var d = this.series[0].data[i];
                    d.dataLabel.translate(0, d.dataLabel.y);
                }
            }
        }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/zLE5R/2/